# WSO2 checking attribute value inside of a JSON with XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a JSON payload which contains attributes inside of it like:

```
{
  "test": "test",
  "test1": "1111",
  "test2": "2222",
  "@test": "3333",
  "test3": [
    {
      "A": "aaaa",
      "@B": "bbbb",
      "c": "cccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using XSLT, I need to check the value of the attibute `@test` or `@B`. Here is my sample transformation for check the attibute `@test` vaue:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//jsonObject/@test='3333'">
      ---- operation ----
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      ---- operation ----
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The problem is here the layer of attributes in my JSON payload. When I move `@B` attribute at the top of its JSON element or `@test` attibute at the top of the JSON element like:

```
{
  "@test": "3333",
  "test": "test",
  "test1": "1111",
  "test2": "2222",
  "test3": [
    {
      "@B": "bbbb",
      "A": "aaaa",
      "c": "cccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can check the attibute values easily. So, is there a way to do that in XSLT instead of using javascript in sequence?

I'm using WSO2 EI 6.4.0
and XSLT 2.0

Best regards.

Comment: Well, it gets a lot easier if you move to XSLT 3.0 which can process the JSON directly, rather than seeing an XML view of it.

Comment: Log the XML representation of the JSON message inside the EI and add that to the post if possible. Then it's much easier to see what kind of xpath would be needed.